# Threads for nozzle (Anet A6 extruder)

Tags: nozzle, anet-a6

How do I know what nozzle to get for my Anet A6 printer? I want to get some hardened nozzles because I would love to print with some glow in the dark filament, but I know that eats up brass nozzles fast. But there is so many thread differences so I don't know which one to get, or even what thread the Anet A6 is. Could I have some help finding the thread type and what hardened nozzles would be recommended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Anet A6 uses the mk8 extruder (also used by the Anet A8). Please search for mk8 nozzles (for 1.75 mm filament). These nozzles use M6 threads. Standard nozzle size is 0.4 mm.

Answer (score 3):

look for MK8 or V6 nozzles that are for 1.75mm filament.

but to answer your question the exact threading is M6 x 1mm thread pitch

both MK8 and e3d v6 nozzles use m6 x 1mm pitch
Source: manual measurement of both my brass mk8 and stainless steel v6 nozzle